# Converting zipfile extracting code from ruby to python

Tags: python, ruby, python-zipfile

I am converting a code from ruby to python that extracts the contents of a zipfile.

I am new to python and not sure how to exactly convert the below code.

ruby code:

```
def extract_from_zipfile(inzipfile)

  txtfile=""
  Zip::File.open(inzipfile) { |zipfile|
    zipfile.each { |file|
      txtfile=file.name
      zipfile.extract(file,file.name) { true }
    }
  }

  return txtfile
end
```

this is my python code:

```
def extract_from_zipfile(inzipfile):

 txtfile=""
 with zipfile.ZipFile(inzipfile,"r") as z:
  z.extractall(txtfile)
 return txtfile
```

it returns the value as none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ruby version, `txtfile` will refer the last extracted file.

In Python, you can get file list using [`zipfile.ZipFile.namelist`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist):

```
def extract_from_zipfile(inzipfile):
    txtfile = ""
    with zipfile.ZipFile(inzipfile, "r") as z:
        z.extractall(txtfile)
        names = z.namelist()    # <---
        if names:               # <--- To prevent IndexError for empty zip file.
            txtfile = names[-1] # <---
    return txtfile
```